# Set JMenu Margin not working

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar, preferredsize

I'm creating a JMenuBar with some JMenu and set margin in each JMenu. But the given margin not working in each JMenu. How to setMargin of JMenu correctly?

```
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class JMenuDemo extends JFrame {

     private JMenuBar bar;

     public JMenuDemo() {
         super("Menu example");
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setVisible(true);

         initialize();
     }

     private void initialize() {
         bar = new JMenuBar();
         int menuHeight = 40;

         JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
         file.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, menuHeight));
         file.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
         file.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 20, 0));

         JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New");
         file.add(newItem);
         JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
         file.add(openItem);
         bar.add(file);

         JMenu test = new JMenu("Test");
         test.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, menuHeight));
         test.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
         test.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 20, 0));
         bar.add(test);

         setJMenuBar(bar);

         getContentPane();
         setSize(400, 200);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName(); 

         java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 new JMenuDemo();
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: JMenuBas uses BoxLayout, read Oracle tutorial ....

Comment: Thanks for your replay @mKorbel. I means how to set text margin of the JMenu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For setting margin you can try to use html code inside your `JMenu`, for example :

```
JMenu file = new JMenu("<html><p style='margin-bottom:20'>File");
```

[image]

Also you can add `EmptyBorder` to your `JMenu` :

```
file.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(file.getBorder(),BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 20, 0)));
```

Comment: How to set image icon and icon margin if i add icon to the menu? I have tried to used html code, but the icon not showing. JMenu jmenuFile = new JMenu("<html><p style='margin-top:10'><img src='./images/kuser.png'/> File</p></html>");. The "images" folder is in "src" folder.

Comment: With case of icon try example with `EmptyBorder`, that helps you. For setting icon use next code `file.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/kuser.png")));
`

Comment: Big thanks to you @alex2410. Your answer and codes help me much.